# How to keep the the io File information such as lastmodifiedDate?

Tags: java, file, io

Iam doing a task that require me to create a quartz job which will automatically read all file in folder, check if any file has the modified date is 1day before today, then copy it to a new folder and delete the old one.

I have already finished impl the quartz job, however, i have no idea to write unittest for this job.

1. Can I create a real file which the specific last modified date to read it? how?
2. Can I copy a real file to new place but still keep its information (last modified date)?
3. Do you have any idea for test this job?

Thank you so much for your help and sorry for my bad english. Thank you!
 (Iam using java6 , not java7)

Comment: 1- Something like [How to change the file last modified date in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-change-the-file-last-modified-date-in-java/); 2- seems like a variation on [1]

Comment: thank you for your answer but i didnt mean to create and set date in a variable. I mean to create a real file in HDD because after that the job will read the real file and get info from that.

Comment: Did you read the example?  Did you try to see if would work?  What do you suppose `file.setLastModified(newDate.getTime());` does?  Did you take the time to have a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setLastModified-long-)?

Comment: yes File file = new File();
i want to set file.setLastModified(newDate.getTime() - 60hoursInMiliseconds);

after that. file.createFile(C:\\myfile.txt)  for example

and the info of myfile still to day, I want to create a REAL file with my last modified, for test my job, because the job will read the real File

Comment: I run the example and it works fine for, I was even able to specify the time.  I was not just reported back by the code, but when I had a look at the file on the disk, it was updated just fine.  Perhaps try writing two test programs, one which shows the `lastModified` time and which changes it, this way you can reassure yourself it's not just been done within the context of the current JVM (ps `File file = new File()` won't compile)